# Add parameters in query on c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, parameters

In my *code behind* of aspx page I have problem to passed values on `Parameters` in sql query.

**I use MySql database.**

**Step 1:**

I add in List the output of an query:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    idcolor = reader["idcolor"].ToString();
    colorList.Add(idcolor.ToString());
}

ns = string.Join("','", colorList.ToArray());
```

In **debug** the output is:

```
ns = red','green
```

**Step 2:**

I need use the values of `string ns` on a sql query.

And pass the values of `string ns` in `parameters`:

```
str = null;
str = ns == null ? "" : ns.ToString();

sql = @" SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN (?); ";

    DataSet dsColors = new DataSet();

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", Server.UrlDecode(str.ToString()));

            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dsColors);
        }
    }

    return dsColors;
```

**Step 3:**

If used in query :

```
sql = @" SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN (?); ";
```

The output in `dataset` is empty.

If used in query :

```
sql = @" SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN ( '" + Server.UrlDecode(str.ToString()) + "' ); ";
```

The output in `dataset` is right.

Anybody know how can I resolve do this?

Can you suggest?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a parameter and place holder for each item you want in your in clause. For example

```
sql = @" SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN (?,?,?); ";
```

Then add the params for each one.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", Server.UrlDecode(str.ToString()));
```

**Example**

```
        List<string> colours = new List<string>();

        colours.Add("black");
        colours.Add("red");

        var placeHolders = string.Join(",",(from colour in colours select "?").ToList());

        var sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN ({0}); ",placeHolders);

        DataSet dsColors = new DataSet();

        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();

            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                foreach(var colour in colours)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(colour, colour);
                }

                OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dsColors);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use  `MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` to connect to Mysql:

```
sql = @" SELECT * FROM Experience WHERE Colors IN (@param1,@param2) ";

    DataSet dsColors = new DataSet();

    using ( MySqlConnection cn =
      new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", colorList[0]/ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2",colorList[1].ToString());    
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlaAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dsColors);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explain what problem you perceived, what you changed and how that fixes the problem.

Comment: use MySqlClient instead of Oldedb

Comment: Dont know why this got downvoted. I just can repeate apomene: Use MySqlClient. Upped.

Comment: the server is in hosting I don't use MySqlClient

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to add a parameter for each color, you can go with

`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString()`

that's not pretty but it's internal used by parameters and you can add a dynamic number of values and you're safe against injection

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    idcolor = reader["idcolor"].ToString();
    colorList.Add(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(idcolor));
}

ns = string.Join("','", colorList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear close with the context, but try getting the results for one color at a time and just keep changing the VALUE of the parameter.  By calling the FILL, it will just keep adding records to the table each time it is called.  However, set your FILL to point to a DataTable instead of a DataSet.  So it doesn't keep putting TABLES into your data set, but instead uses the one continues to append to it.  This would work if you had 1 color or 1000 colors...

```
... rest of previous code BEFORE the OdbcCommand
... and ensure clean values for your colors as others have noted.
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
{
   // Just to add the parameter "place-holder" for your query
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", "");

   // DataTable ONCE to receive all the colors being queried
   DataTable tblAllColors = new DataTable();

   // build the adapter ONCE no matter how many colors you will be querying
   OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);

   // so for this loop, you are just getting the colors one at a time.
   foreach( string s in colorList )
   {
      // next color you are trying to get... just overwrite the 
      // single parameter with the new color.
      adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = s;
      adapter.Fill(tblAllColors);
   }

   // you would otherwise have to build your query dynamically and keep 
   // adding parameter-placeholders "?" for each color in a comma list 
   // as you were attempting... which would be a slightly different query.
}

dsColors.Tables.Add( tblAllColors );
```